# Passing optional <f:attributes> to JSF components within composite components

Tags: jsf, attributes, jsf-2, composite-component

I am looking to pass in attribute values to inner components of a composite component.  The long and short of it is that we are trying to wrap an h:outputLink in some further XHTML.  We wish for the optional use of the DHTML Event attributes that can be used with the outputLink.  We could supply them in the inner component and populate with  values however the rendered XHTML would have numerous empty attribute delcarations (i.e.  etc.).  The hope is that a  passed in as a facet or directly as the content use dwithin .  This does not seem to be working.

A short example of what I thought should work:

```
<core:foo>
   <f:param name="onclick" "alert('hello')"/>
<core:foo>
```

Component File - foo.xhtml

```
<cc:implementation>
    <h:outputLink value="/">
         Test Link
         <cc:insertChildren />
    </h:outputLink>
</cc:implementation>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you define those attributes you want to support as cc:attribtues with default values? For instance: <cc:attribute name="onclick" default="javascript(void)"/>?